# python run functions in modules as a loop

Tags: python

I have the follow functions I have to run... here is the first 3. But the list is long and the it will continue to grow.

```
### 1
try: 
    fr.ftp_link()
    system.append('1')
except: 
    errors.append('1')


### 2
try: 
    md.daily_fetch_all_prices()
    system.append('2')
except: 
    errors.append('2')    

### 3
try: 
    RP.run_daily_RP()
    system.append('3')
except: 
    errors.append('3')
```

I want to make it a loop. Something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(tasks)):
     try:
         execute(tasks[i]) <----- not real code, need help here
         system.append(i)
     except:
         errors.append(i)
```

not sure what `tasks` would look like and how to execute it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have various options. Your current system, where you don't even have a consistent interface for the things that represent tasks, seems like a bad move, but you can easily make a list of functions and iterate through it, or have the tasks implement a particular interface (e.g. they would all have `.execute`) and use `__subclasses__` to iterate over them. As it stands, though, this is not specific enough to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have only functions that do not require arguments, you can go with:

```
tasks = [fr.ftp_link, md.daily_fetch_all_prices, RP.run_daily_RP]
for i, task in enumerate(tasks, start=1):
 try:
     task()
     system.append(str(i))
 except:
     errors.append(str(i))
```

In Python, functions are first-class objects, so you can pass them around, put them in a list, etc. and then just call whatever variable they are assigned to.

In case you have arguments and/or keywords arguments, you'd have to go for a more complicated data structure for tasks, such as a list of tuples of the form `(function, list_of_args, dict_of_kwargs)`
and then go with the following:

```
try:
    function, args, kwargs = task
    function(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: Use enumerate for indexing.

Comment: awesomely simple! thanks